# Cassandra - unable to start server

Tags: bash, cassandra, cqlsh

I have a cassandra server set up on Unix with Bash. I have made no changes to cassandra.yaml
On the command cassandra -f , I get the following errors and exceptions -

```
grep: illegal option -- A
Usage:grep[-c|-l|-q][-bhinsvwx]pattern_list[file ...]
```

I am unable to find GNU Binary for grep to add to my /usr/bin

and

```
 Exception (java.lang.StackOverflowError) encountered during startup: null
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:277)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:814)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1282)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:239)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.Signal.<clinit>(Signal.java:31)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.<clinit>(DefaultPromise.java:42)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:35            )
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:70)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:65)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:56)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:48)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:40)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.NativeTransportService.initialize(NativeTransportService.java:74)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.NativeTransportService.start(NativeTransportService.java:127)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.startNativeTransport(CassandraDaemon.java:649)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:511)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:616)
```

After 2-3 attempts of starting the server, I get the following error -

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
os::commit_memory(0xfffffffe79400000, 3875536896, 0 ) failed; 
error='Resource temporarily unavailable' (errno=11)
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 3875536896 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/vaneet/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.10/bin/hs_err_pid27795.log
```

Comment: What kind of system are you on? Can you give us the non-sensitive parts of the output of `uname -a`? Also can you try running `bash -x $(which cassandra) -f`, so we can see what the script is running before we hit the grep with an illegal option.

Comment: I get the following from uname -a :
`"SunOS sd-mcc01 5.10 Generic_141444-09 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-280R"`
and for bash -x $(which cassandra) -f  : huge log showing CLASSPATH, JVM_OPTS and 
+ '[' 2 -ne 1 ']'
+ echo Unable to bind JMX, is Cassandra already 'running?'
Unable to bind JMX, is Cassandra already running?
+ exit 1

Comment: Few things helped me out - Downloading latest grep source file and then compiling to get grep. 
and changing the JVM memory size using JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024"
Solved with these errors and trying to debug some more to start working with cassandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download latest grep source file and compile to get grep solved the error. Got rid of JVM error by Changing the JVM memory size using JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024"